# ios Swift fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init()'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've been trying very hard, have looked up every similar question pertaining to this issue on StackOverflow and trying them to no avail.

```
class TimeLineTableViewController: 
    UITableViewController,   
    UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
    UINavigationControllerDelegate  {
    
    var timelineData = [PFObject]()
    
    
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.loadData()     
    }

    @IBAction func loadData(){
       timelineData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        
       var findTimelineData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className:"timelineMessages")
       findTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]! , error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                self.timelineData = objects.reverse() as [PFObject]
                //let array:NSArray = self.timelineData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
                // self.timelineData = array as NSMutableArray
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        var footerView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50))
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
        
        var logoutButton:UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        logoutButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 10, 50, 20)
        logoutButton.setTitle("Logout", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        logoutButton.addTarget(self, action:"logout:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        
        footerView.addSubview(logoutButton)
    }
```

To clarify, timelineTableViewController has one class that inherits, MessageTableCell. It's also part of a project that I've integrated into Objective-C code, so it's a combination of both Swift and ObjC. I've run both projects (the swift one and the ObjC one) independently and they work fine; it's only when I try to run it together do they mess up. Any suggestions? I'm at an utter loss for this.

Comment: As for why this happens: it's because Core Animation doesn't perform animations on the layer on the screen. It creates another layer called the presentation layer. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54206705/5175709) and  [here](https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/animations-explained/) (search for _presentation layer_)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

“Unlike subclasses in Objective-C, Swift subclasses do not inherit their superclass initializers by default.”

**Automatic Initializer Inheritance**

- **Rule 1:**
  If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.
- **Rule 2:**
  If your subclass provides an implementation of all of its superclass designated initializers—either by inheriting them as per rule 1, or by providing a custom implementation as part of its definition—then it automatically inherits all of the superclass convenience initializers.

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/tw/jEUH0.l

Since you have override the `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`, `TimeLineTableViewController` won't have the `init()` initiailzer.

You can provide an implementation of all of its superclass designated initialisers like this

```
override init() {
        super.init()
}

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

, or just delete the implementation of `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`.

Comment: Hi, I tried using the last suggestion 'delete implementation of init(coder aDecoder:NSCoder) but when I did, it got errors. Did you mean within other classes?It's TimelineTableViewController-->MessageTableViewCell.

Comment: Hi @Tam, did you implement any initializers in `TimelineTableViewController` or in `MessageTableViewCell` and they do nothing but just call super's initializers? You don't have to override any initializers unless you have some custom initiailzation that must be done when initializing.

Comment: I added the code you had to both. Does MessageTableViewCell need something different? Also, I have a push segue to a UIViewController called ComposeViewController. The original code works in all three (except for the MessageTableViewCell, where I didn't include it) in the original project but not the combined project.

Comment: Does 'MessageTableViewCell` inherit from `UIViewController`? If it does, and you don't have any initialisation code that must be done in initializers, try to remove all initiailzers in both `MessageTableViewCell` and  `TimelineTableViewController`.

Comment: It works now. I ended up deleting all of the inits in all viewcontrollers. Thanks.

Comment: nice, so If I have 10 different initializers in library class, and want to add 1 new init for subclass, I need to write all that boilerplate? wtf