# CABasicAnimation creates empty default value copy of CALayer

Tags: swift, core-animation, calayer, cabasicanimation, radial-gradients

I have a custom CALayer that draws radial gradients. It works great except during animation. It seems that each iteration of `CABasicAnimation` creates a new copy of the `CALayer` subclass with empty, default values for the properties:

[image: debug class]

In the screenshot above, you see that `CABasicAnimation` has created a new copy of the layer and is updating `gradientOrigin` but none of the other properties have come along for the ride.

This has the result of not rendering anything during the animation. Here's a GIF:

[image: improper]

Here's what is should look like:

[image: correct]

Here's the animation code:

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "gradientOrigin")
animation.duration = 2
animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
let newOrigin: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: triangle.bounds.height/2)
animation.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: triangle.gradientLayer.gradientOrigin)
animation.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: newOrigin)
triangle.gradientLayer.gradientOrigin = newOrigin
triangle.gradientLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)
```

Here's the custom CALayer code:

```
enum RadialGradientLayerProperties: String {
  case gradientOrigin
  case gradientRadius
  case colors
  case locations
}

class RadialGradientLayer: CALayer {
  var gradientOrigin = CGPoint() {
    didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
  }
  var gradientRadius = CGFloat() {
    didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
  }

  var colors = [CGColor]() {
    didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
  }

  var locations = [CGFloat]() {
    didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
  }

  override init(){
    super.init()
    needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init()
  }

  override init(layer: AnyObject) {
    super.init(layer: layer)
  }

  override class func needsDisplayForKey(key: String) -> Bool {
    if key == RadialGradientLayerProperties.gradientOrigin.rawValue || key == RadialGradientLayerProperties.gradientRadius.rawValue || key == RadialGradientLayerProperties.colors.rawValue || key == RadialGradientLayerProperties.locations.rawValue {
      print("called \(key)")
      return true
    }
    return super.needsDisplayForKey(key)

  }

  override func actionForKey(event: String) -> CAAction? {
    if event == RadialGradientLayerProperties.gradientOrigin.rawValue || event == RadialGradientLayerProperties.gradientRadius.rawValue || event == RadialGradientLayerProperties.colors.rawValue || event == RadialGradientLayerProperties.locations.rawValue {
      let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: event)
      animation.fromValue = self.presentationLayer()?.valueForKey(event)
      return animation
    }
    return super.actionForKey(event)
  }

  override func drawInContext(ctx: CGContext) {

    guard let colorRef = self.colors.first else { return }

    let numberOfComponents = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(colorRef)
    let colorSpace = CGColorGetColorSpace(colorRef)

    let deepGradientComponents: [[CGFloat]] = (self.colors.map {
      let colorComponents = CGColorGetComponents($0)
      let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: colorComponents, count: numberOfComponents)
      return Array(buffer) as [CGFloat]
      })

    let flattenedGradientComponents = deepGradientComponents.flatMap({ $0 })

    let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, flattenedGradientComponents, self.locations, self.locations.count)

    CGContextDrawRadialGradient(ctx, gradient, self.gradientOrigin, 0, self.gradientOrigin, self.gradientRadius, .DrawsAfterEndLocation)

  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Figured out the answer!

In `init(layer:)` you have to copy the property values to your class manually. Here's how that looks in action:

```
override init(layer: AnyObject) {
  if let layer = layer as? RadialGradientLayer {
    gradientOrigin = layer.gradientOrigin
    gradientRadius = layer.gradientRadius
    colors = layer.colors
    locations = layer.locations
  }
  super.init(layer: layer)
}
```

Comment: From the docs: "This initializer is used to create shadow copies of layers, for example, for the presentationLayer method. Using this method in any other situation will produce undefined behavior. For example, do not use this method to initialize a new layer with an existing layer’s content. If you are implementing a custom layer subclass, you can override this method and use it to copy the values of instance variables into the new object. Subclasses should always invoke the superclass implementation."

Comment: For me I had to use
`override init(layer: Any)` before it would call it correctly, otherwise it can't find the method to override